# How to check if finger is touching the screen using the Unity input system?

Tags: unity, touch

I have a While loop that runs when the mouse is pressed and it look like this:

```
while (mouseClick.ReadValue<float>() != 0)
{
   //Do something
}
```

This works but I want this to work on mobile instead so I am trying to change this to when a finger is touching the screen. I tried this code:

```
    while (touchControls.Touch.TouchPosition.ReadValue<Vector2>() != Vector2.zero)
    {
        //Do something
    }
```

That loop starts to run when a finger presses the screen, but it never stops. And touchControls.Touch.ReadValue() != 0 didn't work either. So how can I make it work like I want?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm assuming you have a yield instruction somewhere in that loop? It might be helpful to show that explicitly.

Comment: Do you mean this line:   yield return null;  ?

Comment: That is indeed a yield instruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to access the `InputSystem` more directly.

You might be looking for [TouchPhase](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.3/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.TouchPhase.html) or use the `Finger` combined with the [EnhancedTouch](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.3/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.EnhancedTouch.EnhancedTouchSupport.html).

```csharp
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem.EnhancedTouch;
using Touch = UnityEngine.InputSystem.EnhancedTouch.Touch;

public class TouchDemo : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        EnhancedTouchSupport.Enable();
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        EnhancedTouchSupport.Disable();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        foreach (var touch in Touch.activeTouches)
        {
            // Only respond to first finger
            if (touch.finger.index == 0 && touch.isInProgress)
            {
                // TODO
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** See the [Touch struct](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.3/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.EnhancedTouch.Touch.html) for more information about the various states of a Touch.

Comment: Thanks that answer helped me, but it seems like "inProgress" should be changed to "isInProgress".

Comment: You are absolutely right! My bad. I've corrected it now.